# Android Save values of Edittexts in SharedPreference

Tags: java, android, save, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

In my Android app.. I would like to save the details of users to SharedPreference.. In the same app I am using sharedpreference for saving login information and it is working fine..  the same method I used to save the user details.. but it is not working and the appp is crashing.. In user details users first name, middle name and lastname along with his date of birth is collected.. I am giving my code here. please help..

UserDetailsActivity:

```
public void gReport(View V)

    {











        long sum1 = 0;
        long sum2 = 0;
        long sum3 = 0;
        long sum7 = 0;
        long sum8 = 0;
        long sum9 = 0;
        long sum10 = 0;
        long sum11 = 0;
        long sum12 = 0;
        long sum13 = 0;
        long sum14 = 0;
        long sum15 = 0;
        long sum16 = 0;
        long sum17 = 0;
        long sum18 = 0;
        long sum19 = 0;
        long sum20 = 0;
        long sum22 = 0;
        long sum23 = 0;
        long sum24 = 0;
        long sum25 = 0;
        long sum70 = 0;
        long sum80 = 0;
        long sum90 = 0;
        //Destiny Number Karmic Debt
        long kar1 = 0;
        long kar2 = 0;
        long kar3 = 0;
        long kar7 = 0;
        //Heart Number Karmic Debt
        long kar4 = 0;
        long kar5 = 0;
        long kar6 = 0;
        long kar8 = 0;
        //Talent Number Karmic Debt
        //long kar9 = 0;
        long kar10 = 0;
        long kar11 = 0;
        //Personality Number Karmic Debt
        long kar12 = 0;
        long kar13 = 0;
        long kar14 = 0;
        long kar15 = 0;
        //Minor expression Number Karmic Debt
        long kar16 = 0;
        long kar17 = 0;
        long kar18 = 0;
        long kar19 = 0;

        //Minor Heart Desire Number Karmic Debt
        long kar20 = 0;
        long kar21 = 0;
        long kar22 = 0;
        long kar23 = 0;

        //Minor Personality Number Karmic Debt
        long kar24 = 0;
        long kar25 = 0;
        long kar26 = 0;
        long kar27 = 0;
        //Balance Number Karmic Debt
        long kar28 = 0;
        //year now to single digit
        long yearnow = 0;
        //month now to single digit
        long monthnow = 0;
        //Day now to single digit
        long daynow = 0;

        long ch = 0;
        long ch1 = 0;
        long ch2 = 0;
        long ch4 = 0;
        long ch3 = 0;
        long pin1 = 0;
        long pin2 = 0;
        long pin3 = 0;
        long pin4 = 0;
        long pin = 0;
        long br1 = 0;
        long br2 = 0;
        long br3 = 0;
        long a =0;

        int yearat =0;
        int monthat = 0;
        int dayat = 0;



        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        yearat = gc.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        yearstr = Integer.toString(yearat);
        monthat = gc.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        monthstr = Integer.toString(monthat);
        dayat = gc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        daystr = Integer.toString(dayat);




        List<Integer> sum21;


        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
        EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText2);
        EditText et3 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText3);

        EditText et4 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText4);
        EditText et5 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText5);
        EditText et6 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText6);

        EditText et7 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText7);        
        EditText et8 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText8);
        EditText et9 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText9);






        sum1 = getSum1(et1.getText().toString());
        sum2 = getSum2(et2.getText().toString());
        sum3 = getSum3(et3.getText().toString());

        sum7 = getSum7(et7.getText().toString());
        sum8 = getSum8(et8.getText().toString());
        sum9 = getSum9(et9.getText().toString());

        sum11 = getSum11((et7.getText().toString()) + (et8.getText().toString()) + (et9.getText().toString()));
        sum12 = getSum12(et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString());

        sum13 = getSum13(et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString());
        sum14 = getSum14(et4.getText().toString() + et5.getText().toString() + et6.getText().toString());
        sum15 = getSum15(et4.getText().toString() + et5.getText().toString() + et6.getText().toString());
        sum16 = getSum16(et4.getText().toString() + et5.getText().toString() + et6.getText().toString());
        sum18 = getSum18((yearstr) + (et7.getText().toString() + et8.getText().toString()));
        sum19 = getSum19((monthstr) + (sum18));
        sum20 = getSum20((daystr) + sum19);
        sum21 = getMissingNo(et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString());

        //Destiny Numberkarmic debt
        kar1 = getKar1(et1.getText().toString());
        kar2 = getKar2(et2.getText().toString());
        kar3 = getKar3(et3.getText().toString());
        kar7 = getKar7(et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString());
        //Heart Number karmic debt
        kar4 = getKar4(et1.getText().toString());
        kar5 = getKar5(et2.getText().toString());
        kar6 = getKar6(et3.getText().toString());
        kar8 = getKar8(et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString());
        //Talent Number Karmic Debt
        //kar9 = getKar9(et7.getText().toString());

        kar10 = getKar10(et9.getText().toString());
        kar11 = getKar11(et7.getText().toString() + et8.getText().toString() + et9.getText().toString());

        //Personality Number karmic Debt

        kar12 = getKar12(et1.getText().toString());
        kar13 = getKar13(et2.getText().toString());
        kar14 = getKar14(et3.getText().toString());
        kar15 = getKar15(et1.getText().toString() + et2.getText().toString() + et3.getText().toString());

        //Minor Expression Number Karmic Debt Calculation

        kar16 = getKar16(et4.getText().toString());
        kar17 = getKar17(et5.getText().toString());
        kar18 = getKar18(et6.getText().toString());
        kar19 = getKar19(et4.getText().toString() + et5.getText().toString() + et6.getText().toString());

        //Minor Heart Desire Number karmic debt
        kar20 = getKar20(et4.getText().toString());
        kar21 = getKar21(et5.getText().toString());
        kar22 = getKar22(et6.getText().toString());
        kar23 = getKar23(et4.getText().toString() + et5.getText().toString() + et6.getText().toString());

        //Minor Personality Number karmic Debt

        kar24 = getKar24(et4.getText().toString());
        kar25 = getKar25(et5.getText().toString());
        kar26 = getKar26(et6.getText().toString());
        kar27 = getKar27(et4.getText().toString() + et5.getText().toString() + et6.getText().toString());

        //First Pinnacle Karmic Debt




        sum70 = getsum70(et7.getText().toString());
        sum80 = getSum80(et8.getText().toString());
        sum90 = getSum90(et9.getText().toString());



        sum10 = getSum10 ((et1.getText().toString()) + (et2.getText().toString()) + (et3.getText().toString()));
        pin1  = getSumpin1(Integer.toString((int)sum70) + Integer.toString((int) sum80));
        pin2  = getSumpin2(Integer.toString((int)sum70) + Integer.toString((int)sum90));
        pin3  = getSumpin3(Integer.toString((int)pin1) + Integer.toString((int)pin2));
        pin4  = getSumpin4(Integer.toString((int)sum80) + Integer.toString((int)sum90));


        String firstName     = et1.getText().toString();
        String middleName    = et2.getText().toString();
        String lastName      = et3.getText().toString();
        String callFirstName = et4.getText().toString();
        String dates         = et7.getText().toString();
        String months        = et8.getText().toString();
        String years         = et9.getText().toString();

        String aChar3 = "";



        if(firstName.trim().length()>0)

           {
            aChar3 = firstName.substring(0,1);
           }

        String aChar4 = "";

        if(middleName.trim().length()>0)

           {
            aChar4 = middleName.substring(0,1);
           }

        String aChar5 = "";

        if (lastName.trim().length()>0)

           {
            aChar5 = lastName.substring(0,1);
           }







        StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(aChar3);
        sb.append(aChar4);
        sb.append(aChar5);
        String aChar6 = sb.toString();
        sum22 = getSum22(String.valueOf(aChar6));
        //Balance Number Karmic Debt
        kar28 = getKar28(String.valueOf(aChar6));

        char aChar = firstName.charAt(0);
        int strLength = firstName.length();
        char aChar1 = firstName.charAt(strLength-1);
        char aChar2 = gReport1(V);
        int itemCount =9 - sum21.size();


        sum23 = getSum23(String.valueOf(aChar1));
        sum24 = getSum24(String.valueOf(aChar));
        sum25 = getSum25(String.valueOf(aChar2));

        //GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        //int yearat = gc.get(Calendar.YEAR);


        int day1 = Integer.parseInt(et7.getText().toString());
        int month1 = Integer.parseInt(et8.getText().toString());
        int year1 = Integer.parseInt(et9.getText().toString());



       String s1 = String.valueOf(FullExplanationEntry.this.getAge(year1, month1, day1));






        int val = 0;
        long val1  = sum11;
        //long val   = sum16;
        val = Integer.valueOf(s1);
        long val2  = 36 - val1;
        int val4   = 9;

        long val5  = val2 + val4;

        long val6  = val5 + val4;

        long val7  = val6 + 80;


        long val18 = val2 + 1;
        long val19 = val5 + 1;
        long val20 = val6 + 1;

        long pYear = 0;




        if (sum70 > sum80)
        {
            ch1 = (sum70 - sum80);
        }
        else
        {
            ch1 = (sum80 - sum70);
        }

        if (sum70 > sum90)
        {
            ch2 = (sum70 - sum90);
        }
        else
        {
            ch2 = (sum90 - sum70);
        }

        if (sum80 > sum90)
        {
            ch4 = (sum80 - sum90);
        }
        else
        {
            ch4 = (sum90 - sum80);
        }

        if (ch1 > ch2)
        {
            ch3 = ch1 - ch2;
        }
        else
        {
            ch3 = ch2 - ch1;
        }



        if (val <= val2)
        {
            ch = ch1;
        }


        else if ((val > val2) && (val <= val5))
        {
            ch = ch2;
        }

        else if ((val > val2) && (val> val5) && (val <= val6))
        {
            ch = ch3;
        }

        else if ((val > val2) && (val> val5) && (val > val6) && (val<= val7))
        {
            ch = ch4;
        }


        if (val <= val2)
        {
            pin = pin1;
        }


        else if ((val > val2) && (val <= val5))
        {
            pin = pin2;
        }

        else if ((val > val2) && (val> val5) && (val <= val6))
        {
            pin = pin3;
        }

        else if ((val > val2) && (val> val5) && (val > val6) && (val<= val7))
        {
            pin = pin4;
        }


        if (sum11 > sum10)
        {
            br1 = sum11 - sum10;
        }
        else
        {
            br1 = sum10 - sum11;
        }
        if(sum12 > sum13)
        {
            br2 = sum12 - sum13;
        }
        else
        {
            br2 = sum13 - sum12;
        }
        if(sum10 > sum12)
        {
            br3 = sum10 - sum12;
        }
        else
        {
            br3 = sum12 - sum10;
        }

        int dayS = Integer.parseInt(et7.getText().toString());
        int monthS = Integer.parseInt(et8.getText().toString());
        int yearS = Integer.parseInt(et9.getText().toString());
        yearnow = getSumYear(String.valueOf(yearat));
        monthnow = getSumMonth(String.valueOf(monthat));
        daynow = getSumDay(String.valueOf(dayat));
        //pYear = getKarPyar(String.valueOf(yearat));
        //Karmic Debt Pinnacle
        int karPin1 = 0;
        long karPin2 = 0;
        long karPin3 = 0;
        int karPin4 = 0;
        //Karmic day
        int karDay = 0;
        long karYear = 0;
        //Karmic Debt Personal Year
        long karPyr = 0;
        long karPmn = 0;
        long karPdy = 0;
        int kPin1 = Integer.parseInt(et7.getText().toString()) + Integer.parseInt(et8.getText().toString());
        long kPin2 = sum9 + Integer.parseInt(et7.getText().toString());
        long kPin3 = pin1 + pin2;
        long kPin4 = sum9 + Integer.parseInt(et8.getText().toString());
        long kPyr = yearnow + kPin1;
        long kPmn = monthnow + kPyr;
        long kPdy = daynow + kPmn;
        karYear = getKarYear(String.valueOf(yearnow));


        //Karmic Debt First Pinnacle
        if(kPin1 == 13)
        {
            karPin1 = 13;
        }
        else if(kPin1 == 14)
        {
            karPin1 = 14;
        }
        else if(kPin1 == 16)
        {
            karPin1 = 16;
        }
        else if(kPin1 == 19)
        {
            karPin1 = 19;
        }
        else
        {
            karPin1 = 0;
        }
        //Karmic Debt Pinnacle 2
        if(kPin2 == 13)
        {
            karPin2 = 13;
        }
        else if(kPin2 == 14)
        {
            karPin2 = 14;
        }
        else if(kPin2 == 16)
        {
            karPin2 = 16;
        }
        else if(kPin2 == 19)
        {
            karPin2 = 19;
        }
        else
        {
            karPin2 = 0;
        }
        //Karmic Debt Pinnacle 3
        if(kPin3 == 13)
        {
            karPin3 = 13;
        }
        else if(kPin3 == 14)
        {
            karPin3 = 14;
        }
        else if(kPin3 == 16)
        {
            karPin3 = 16;
        }
        else if(kPin3 == 19)
        {
            karPin3 = 19;
        }
        else
        {
            karPin3 = 0;
        }
      //Karmic Debt Pinnacle 4
        if(kPin4 == 13)
        {
            karPin4 = 13;
        }
        else if(kPin4 == 14)
        {
            karPin4 = 14;
        }
        else if(kPin4 == 16)
        {
            karPin4 = 16;
        }
        else if(kPin4 == 19)
        {
            karPin4 = 19;
        }
        else
        {
            karPin4 = 0;
        }
      //Karmic Debt Personal Year No
        if(kPyr == 13)
        {
            karPyr = 13;
        }
        else if(kPyr == 14)
        {
            karPyr = 14;
        }
        else if(kPyr == 16)
        {
            karPyr = 16;
        }
        else if(kPyr == 19)
        {
            karPyr = 19;
        }
        else
        {
            karPyr = 0;
        }
      //Karmic Debt Personal Month No
        if(kPmn == 13)
        {
            karPmn = 13;
        }
        else if(kPmn == 14)
        {
            karPmn = 14;
        }
        else if(kPmn == 16)
        {
            karPmn = 16;
        }
        else if(kPmn == 19)
        {
            karPmn = 19;
        }
        else
        {
            karPmn = 0;
        }
      //Karmic Debt Personal Day No
        if(kPdy == 13)
        {
            karPdy = 13;
        }
        else if(kPdy == 14)
        {
            karPdy = 14;
        }
        else if(kPdy == 16)
        {
            karPdy = 16;
        }
        else if(kPdy== 19)
        {
            karPdy = 19;
        }
        else
        {
            karPdy = 0;
        }
      //Karmic Debt day
        if(dayS == 13)
        {
            karDay = 13;
        }
        else if(dayS == 14)
        {
            karDay = 14;
        }
        else if(dayS == 16)
        {
            karDay = 16;
        }
        else if(dayS == 19)
        {
            karDay = 19;
        }
        else
        {
            karDay = 0;
        }




        if(firstName.equals(""))
        {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First Name should not be left blank.. Please enter your First Name and try once again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
        }

        else if(lastName.equals(""))
        {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Last Name should not be left blank.. Please enter your Last Name and try once again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
        }

        else if(callFirstName.equals(""))
        {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your First Name that is currently used and try once again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
        }





        else
        {   

            SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editors = setting.edit();
            editors.putString("log", "log");
            editors.commit(); 


            Intent i = new Intent(this, TabLayoutActivity.class);
        //Intent i = new Intent(this, FullExplanation.class);
        //Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondResult.class);



            //Personal Year
            i.putExtra("name18",sum18 + "");
            //Personal Month
            i.putExtra("name19",sum19 + "");
            //Personal Dya
            i.putExtra("name20",sum20 + "");
            //Current Pinnacle
            i.putExtra("pin", pin + "");
            //Current Challenge
            i.putExtra("ch", ch + "");

            i.putExtra("yearstr", yearstr);
            i.putExtra("monthstr", monthstr);
            i.putExtra("daystr", daystr);



            startActivity(i);


                }



            }
```

MainActivity

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "LoginPrefs";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.directcalc_xm);


        /*
         * Check if we successfully logged in before. 
         * If we did, redirect to calculation page
         */
        SharedPreferences setting = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

                /*if (settings.getString("logged", "").toString().equals("logged")) 
                {
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FullExplanationEntry.class);
                        startActivity(intent2);
                } */

                if (setting.getString("log", "").toString().equals("log")) 
                {
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(DirectCalculation.this,TabLayoutActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                } 


                else
                {
                    btn1 = (Button) findViewById ( R.id.button1);
                    btn2 = (Button) findViewById ( R.id.button2);

                    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignInActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });
```

logcat

```
01-20 12:27:39.684: I/dalvikvm(4750): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-20 12:27:40.301: I/dalvikvm(4750): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-20 12:27:44.073: I/Choreographer(4750): Skipped 224 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-20 12:27:55.383: I/Choreographer(4750): Skipped 97 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-20 12:27:59.350: D/gralloc_goldfish(4750): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-20 12:28:00.944: I/Choreographer(4750): Skipped 73 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-20 12:34:36.303: D/dalvikvm(4750): GC_CONCURRENT freed 94K, 8% free 2692K/2916K, paused 370ms+127ms, total 1369ms
01-20 12:34:36.724: I/Choreographer(4750): Skipped 77 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-20 12:34:40.427: D/AndroidRuntime(4750): Shutting down VM
01-20 12:34:40.463: W/dalvikvm(4750): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.numero/com.example.numero.TabLayoutActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     at com.example.numero.TabLayoutActivity.getCalc(TabLayoutActivity.java:107)
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     at com.example.numero.TabLayoutActivity.onCreate(TabLayoutActivity.java:41)
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     ... 11 more
01-20 12:34:45.824: I/Process(4750): Sending signal. PID: 4750 SIG: 9
```

tablayoutActivity

```
public class TabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity
```

{

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "LoginPrefs";

String pyear, pmonth, pday,chn, pinn;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.tablay_xm);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    pyear = getIntent().getStringExtra("name18");
    pmonth = getIntent().getStringExtra("name19");
    pday = getIntent().getStringExtra("name20");
    pinn = getIntent().getStringExtra("pin");
    chn= getIntent().getStringExtra("ch");
    //value for current year, month and day.
    String yearstring = getIntent().getStringExtra("yearstr");
    String monthstring = getIntent().getStringExtra("monthstr");
    String ms = getCalc(monthstring);

    String daystring = getIntent().getStringExtra("daystr");




    // Tab for Personal Year
    TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Personal Year");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    photospec.setIndicator(yearstring, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
    Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, TabPersonalYr.class);
    //Intent for passing the value of Personal Year
    photosIntent.putExtra("pyear", pyear);
    photosIntent.putExtra("pinn", pinn);


    photospec.setContent(photosIntent);     



    // Tab for Personal Month
    TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Personal Month");        
    songspec.setIndicator(daystring  + " " +  ms, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_songs_tab));
    Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, TabPersonalMnth.class);
    //Intent for passing the value of Personal Month
    songsIntent.putExtra("pmonth", pmonth);
    songsIntent.putExtra("pday", pday);

    songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

    // Tab for Videos
    TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Personal Day");
    videospec.setIndicator("Challenge", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_videos_tab));
    Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, TabPersonalDay.class);
    //Intent for passing the value of Currrent Challenge
    videosIntent.putExtra("chn", chn);
    videospec.setContent(videosIntent);

    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding Personal Year tab
    tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding Personal Month , Day tab
    tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding Challenge tab


    for (int i = 0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_videos_tab);
        TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
       // tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    }
    TextView t = (TextView) tabHost.getCurrentTabView().findViewById(android.R.id.title); //for Selected Tab
    t.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));



}







private String getCalc(String monthstring) {
        String ms = "0";
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(monthstring.equals("1"))            // line number 107
        {
            ms= "January";
            return ms;
        }
        else if(monthstring.equals("2"))
        {
            ms= "February";
            return ms;
        }

        else if(monthstring.equals("3"))
        {
            ms= "March";
            return ms;
        }

        else if(monthstring.equals("4"))
        {
            ms= "April";
            return ms;
        }

        else if(monthstring.equals("5"))
        {
            ms= "May";
            return ms;
        }

        else if(monthstring.equals("6"))
        {
            ms= "June";
            return ms;
        }

        else if(monthstring.equals("7"))
        {
            ms= "July";
            return ms;
        }

        else if(monthstring.equals("8"))
        {
            ms= "August";
            return ms;
        }

        else if(monthstring.equals("9"))
        {
            ms= "September";
            return ms;
        }

        else if(monthstring.equals("10"))
        {
            ms= "October";
            return ms;
        }

        else if(monthstring.equals("11"))
        {
            ms= "November";
            return ms;
        }

        else if(monthstring.equals("12"))
        {
            ms= "December";
            return ms;
        }
        else
            return "0";

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.button04) {
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.remove("logged");
                    editor.commit();
                    finish();
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);



}
}
```

Comment: ya... I declared the activity

Comment: In tablayout activity I am using tabhost.. is that a problem ..?

Comment: could you post TabLayoutActivity.java line 107?

Comment: I updated the tablayoutActivity.. please check

Comment: private String getCalc(String monthstring) {
  String ms = "0";
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  if(monthstring.equals("1"))            // line number 107
  {
   ms= "January";
   return ms;
  }

Comment: if(monthstring.equals("1"))   .. This is the line 107.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("monthstr");
```

returns null.
First of all I suggest you to write the if condition more null safety:

```
if("1".equals(monthstring))
```

will never throws a `NPE`.
Furthermore: `monthstr` is `null`.
you passed it with a `null` value.
Unfortunality you dont post enough code to see the reason for that.
Please post the whole class `UserDetailsActivity`

Comment: I updated the userdetailsActivity... that is FullExplanationEntry.class.. please check...

Comment: thanks Stefan.. I accepted your answer... because from your answer ..I  got clue for solving the prole,.. Actually I was not saving any value.. tthats y I got null values..

Answer (score 0):

```
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-20 12:34:40.913: E/AndroidRuntime(4750):     at com.example.numero.TabLayoutActivity.getCalc(TabLayoutActivity.java:107)
```

can you show the TabLayoutActivity? i believe the problem is there..

**EDIT** -
The problem seems to be that you declared the "monthString" inside the onCreate function.
you should declare it outside(where you declared the pyear string and such) and it will solve that problem..

Comment: only tomorrow I could check the code ...bec now I am in house...I will accept answer once I checked...thanks 4 u r help

Answer (score 0):

The variable monthstring is NULL, so monthstring.equals() throws a null pointer exception.

Because in MainActivity:

```
if (setting.getString("log", "").toString().equals("log")) 
            {
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(DirectCalculation.this,TabLayoutActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
            }
```

you've forgot to set Extra data.